# Property Methods vs Fields in C#

Tags: c#, properties

Using C# - If I have a property of an object that, say, returns the number of elements in an array which is a field of that object, like `NumCols` below:

```
public string[][] Table { get; }  // Jagged 2D Table
public int NumRows { get { return Table.Length; } }  // number of rows in the table
public int[] NumCols {
    // number of columns in each row
    get
    {
        var NumCols = new int[NumRows];
        for (int i=0; i<NumRows; i++) { NumCols[i] = Table[i].Length; }
        return NumCols;
    }
}
```

If I am going to be referencing this `NumCols` property a lot, will it be a performance problem that it has to recompute this statistic each time?  Is the runtime smart enough to not recompute this every time if `Table` has not changed?  Should I manually make this a field, and then update it as I need to instead?

Comment: i think so it will be computed every time

Comment: With C# 6, `NumRows` can be written as this: `public int NumRows => Table.Length;` Just makes it much easier to read.

Comment: @AustinWBryan: great tip, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property getters will be executed whenever the property value is accessed. In that way, they are identical to a method `Get<PropertyName>` that just returns the value.

If you want to avoid that, you should consider caching the value, e.g. using a lazy approach like this:

```
private int[] numCols = null;
public int[] NumCols
{
    get
    {
        if (numCols == null)
        {
            numCols = ExpensiveCalculation();
        }
        return numCols;
    }
}
```

In general, you should avoid placing expensive things within property getters as the expectation with properties is that you can access the value very quickly with very little overhead. If you find yourself having a more complex process to get to a value, and caching as above is not appropriate, then you should consider writing a real get method instead. That way, users of the method will implicitly know that there is an overhead compared to a simple property:

```
public int[] GetNumCols()
{
     return ExpensiveCalculation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no automatic reuse of the calculated result of the method. This would be bad for a number of reasons, not the least of which would be that multiple callers could get the same array (by reference) as a result.

If you want that behavior, it's fairly easy to create. Just store the result in a field and clear the field any time the stored array changes.

Answer (score 0):

Like all optimization, it depends. You can probably speed it up by caching the results (that will *not* happen automatically), but whether the time taken to do that would be worthwhile - when measured against the other things in your program that you could speed up - it's impossible to say without doing some measurement.

Ideally, you should optimize the things that will actually make a measurable difference. Even if you find that the program is slow, you'd want to run a profiler before assuming that it's this that's causing the problem. Indeed, if your design requires `NumCols` to be accessed "a lot", that might indicate that the design should change rather than this particular bit of implementation.

Comment: Thanks - can you explain what you mean by "the design should change"?  Is it necessarily a bad thing that a property is accessed often?

Comment: @dashnick No, not if the property is simply retrieving a value rather than performing some calculation. I think my niggling concern was that I couldn't imagine why a list of the number of columns in each row of a jagged array would be something that you'd need to access repeatedly (e.g. in a tight loop). Without seeing the rest of your code, I really cant comment (and shouldn't have made that comment).

Answer (score 0):

In C#, it is considered good practice to never use public fields, and to only use properties. If the overhead is large, you can put it into a method instead like `GetNumCols()`, and this will tell the user that this is a method that will likely have an overhead, as opposed to just being a normal field.